# Translating English to predicate logic with units

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I am having difficulty translating this fragment from a larger sentence into predicate logic: three pets bathe together.

Let pets be P(x) and B(x,y) be bathe togehter.

How would I deal with the number 3 in this scenario?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not $\exists x \exists y \exists z,P(x)\&P(y)\&P(z)\&B(x,y)\&B(y,z)\&B(z,x)$ ?

Comment: Any comment ? ...

Comment: Would we then assure that we have exactly 3? It seems to me we need to ensure that x, y and z are distinct from each other. And also we need something to ensure that there are no more other bathing pets...so maybe something similar to 'for any other pet that is bathing with some pet, these pets are among the already handled x, y, and z'. though...of course I admit, the task is not perfectly clear in this regard, I think.

Comment: You do **not** need to restrict yourself to exactly three pets.  You do need to ensure that you have three **distinct** animals.

Comment: **Remark:** If we interpret that no animal may "Bathe Together" with itself, then that is enough to ensure distinctness.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say "Two pets bathe together."

$\qquad\exists x~\exists y~\big(x\,{\neq}\,y\land P(x)\land P(y)\land B(x,y)\big)$

"There exists two distinct animals which are both pets, and they bathe together."

---

Now to say it for three is just a little more busy.

$\qquad\exists x~\exists y~\exists z~\big(x\,{\neq}\,y\land x\,{\neq}\, z\land y\,{\neq}\, z\land P(x)\land P(y)\land P(z)\land B(x,y)\land B(x,z)\land B(y,z)\big)$

---

**Remark:** If the "Bathe together" predicate is irreflexive, then it will make the inequality redundant. (Ie: When we interpret it to be that no animal may "Bathe Together" with itself, then that will ensure distinctness.)

Comment: Also if we assume that bathing together is not only symmetric but also transitive, we can get rid of one of the bathing predications.

Comment: Although, there is no reason to presume transitivity, since pets *may* bathe at different times.